# Python Binary conversion

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to convert some binary output from a file to different types, and I keep seeing odd things.

For instance, I have:

```
value = '\x11'
```

If you do

```
bin(ord(value))
```

you get the output

```
'0b10001'
```

whereas I was hoping to get

```
'0b00010001'
```

I'm basically trying to read in a 32 byte header, turn it into 1's and 0's, so I can grab various bits that have different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use bitwise operators?

```
def is_bit_set(i, x):
    """Check if the i-th bit in x is set"""
    return x & (1 << i) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the desired output, try:

```
"0b{:08b}".format(ord(value))
```

If efficiency is your concern, it's recommended to use native binary representation instead of literal(string) binary representation, for bitwise operation is much more compact and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`format(ord('\x11'), '08b')` will get you `00010001`, which should be close enough to what you want.